# Oracle view in NOT EXISTS query not working

Tags: oracle, view, not-exists

I have the following query that is not working. It returns all the rows from inv view.  When I copied the view to a static table and use the static table in the query, the query works as it should and only results in a few rows.  So something is wrong with using a view with a NOT EXISTS subquery.  Can someone explain if this is true or if I have another error.

Update: In our dev environment, the exact same query is working fine. Now I am even more confused.

```
SELECT inv.organization_id, inv.inventory_item_id
  FROM inventory_v inv
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                     FROM inventory_int xx
                    WHERE xx.item_id = inv.inventory_item_id 
                      AND xx.org_id = inv.organization_id
                  )
;
```

Update: See explain plan for dev query that works, and prod query that does not work.  I don't really know how to interpret it.

[image: Query that works]

[image: Query that DOES NOT work]

Update: Still can't figure it out.  Weird that the production explain plan does not have the filter, but the dev one does.  Production db is 12c, dev db is 19c.

PROD

```
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   2 - access("INVENTORY_ITEM_ID"(+)="MSI"."INVENTORY_ITEM_ID" AND "ORGANIZATION_ID"(+)="MSI"."ORGANIZATION_ID")
   5 - access("ORG"."ORGANIZATION_ID"="MSI"."ORGANIZATION_ID")
   7 - access("SUB"."SUBINVENTORY_CODE"="OH"."SUBINVENTORY_CODE" AND "SUB"."PRIMARY_SHIPPING_ORG_ID"="OH"."ORGANIZATION_ID")
   9 - access("MSI"."ORGANIZATION_ID"="PRIMARY_SHIPPING_ORG_ID")
  11 - access("ERP_ORG_ID"=TO_NUMBER("CONTROL_VALUE"))
  12 - filter("EXTRACT_TYPE"='ORG' AND "ACTIVE_FLAG"='Y')
  13 - access("CONTROL_TYPE"='SFC_E_EBS_OPERATING_UNIT')
  15 - access("OH"."ORGANIZATION_ID"="MSI"."ORGANIZATION_ID" AND "OH"."INVENTORY_ITEM_ID"="MSI"."INVENTORY_ITEM_ID")
```

DEV

```
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   2 - filter( NOT EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM "SFC_E_INVENTORY_INT" "XX" WHERE "XX"."ITEM_ID"=:B1 AND "XX"."ORG_ID"=:B2))
   3 - access("INVENTORY_ITEM_ID"(+)="MSI"."INVENTORY_ITEM_ID" AND "ORGANIZATION_ID"(+)="MSI"."ORGANIZATION_ID")
   6 - access("ORG"."ORGANIZATION_ID"="MSI"."ORGANIZATION_ID")
   8 - access("SUB"."SUBINVENTORY_CODE"="OH"."SUBINVENTORY_CODE" AND "SUB"."PRIMARY_SHIPPING_ORG_ID"="OH"."ORGANIZATION_ID")
  10 - access("MSI"."ORGANIZATION_ID"="PRIMARY_SHIPPING_ORG_ID")
  12 - access("ERP_ORG_ID"=TO_NUMBER("CONTROL_VALUE"))
  13 - filter("EXTRACT_TYPE"='ORG' AND "ACTIVE_FLAG"='Y')
  14 - access("CONTROL_TYPE"='SFC_E_EBS_OPERATING_UNIT')
  16 - access("OH"."ORGANIZATION_ID"="MSI"."ORGANIZATION_ID" AND "OH"."INVENTORY_ITEM_ID"="MSI"."INVENTORY_ITEM_ID")
  19 - access("XX"."ORG_ID"=:B1 AND "XX"."ITEM_ID"=:B2)
```

Comment: Your code works [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_F_OGkma). If you think that it does not work then provide a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE`, `CREATE VIEW` and `INSERT` statements for some sample data and details of the issue/error and the expected output for that sample data. Just stating that it is "not working" is not constructive as it does not explain to us why you think it is not working or how you think it should work.

Comment: Thanks @MTO.  The problem was that it was returning all rows from inv table, instead of only the few expected rows that satisfied the NOT EXISTS clause.  But now I found in our DEV environment, the query works as expected.  A compare of the view and query show them as identical, so I'm still searching for root-cause.

Comment: If any of the correlation columns are strings rather than numbers, check the column  definitions match (so you aren't comparing `char` with `varchar2`, say) and look for trailing spaces that might prevent a match despite superficially looking the same.

Comment: get the explain plan of the non-working version, and check the predicates part to see what it is doing.

Comment: HI can you  check with one specific row which is returned and compare the data with the view and the table created from the view and see if you see any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the view was referencing a table over a dblink to another Oracle instance.  I think maybe I encountered a bug in 12c, because it works fine in 19c.  I moved the NOT EXISTS inside the view, and that solved the problem for me.